# Trying to get non null PDF response from my PDF service, .net API and Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have an issue with getting a PDF document from an API setup with c# .net. The PDF creation is handled by Puppeteer and setup with a Dockerised Azure Function. I have made successful requests to this endpoint and got the expected results, so I am happy that side of things is working.

The problem I am having is using the Azure Function from within my c# .net API project:

A few files:

My PDF service:

```
public class PdfService : IPdfService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public PdfService(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _config = configuration;

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-functions-key", _config["PdfService:ApiKey"]);
    }

    public async Task<Stream> GeneratePdfAsync(GeneratePdfRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(_config["PdfService:Url"], httpContent, cancellationToken);

        if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"Error: {response.StatusCode}, Failed to generate PDF!");
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost("summaryreport")]
    [MustHavePermission(FSHAction.View, FSHResource.ResidentFormAnswers)]
    [OpenApiOperation("Get resident answer summary report.", "")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadResidentAnswerSummary(GetResidentAnswerSummaryReport request)
    {
        Stream stream = await Mediator.Send<Stream>(request);
        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf")
        {
            FileDownloadName = $"ResidentAnswerSummary.pdf"
        };
    }
```

The Request Handle:

```
public class GetResidentAnswerSummaryReportHandler : IRequestHandler<GetResidentAnswerSummaryReport, Stream>
{

  private readonly IRepository<ResidentFormAnswer> _repository;
  private readonly ISender _mediator;
  private readonly IPdfService _pdfService;
  public GetResidentAnswerSummaryReportHandler(IRepository<ResidentFormAnswer> repository, ISender mediator, IPdfService pdfService)
  {
    _repository = repository;
    _mediator = mediator;
    _pdfService = pdfService;
  }

/* ---Removed Code For Brevity--- */

public async Task<Stream> Handle(GetResidentAnswerSummaryReport request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var answers = await _mediator.Send(
      new GetResidentFormAnswersRequest(
        request.ContainerFormIds.ToArray(),
        request.ResidentId,
        request.RecordDate,
        ResidentFormAnswer.CheckStatus.Approved),
      cancellationToken);

    List<AnswerSummaryDto> answerSummary = GroupResidentFormAnswers(answers);
    string html = new AnswerSummaryReport().GenerateHtml(answerSummary);
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(html)) throw new Exception("Error: Empty HTML returned!");
    html = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
    var pdfStream = await _pdfService.GeneratePdfAsync(new GeneratePdfRequest { Title = "Report", Html = html }, cancellationToken);

    using (var fileStream = File.Create("test.pdf"))
    {
      pdfStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      pdfStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }

    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    return pdfStream;
  }
}
```

At present when I use the endpoint I literately receive a PDF with the word null in it! Clearly something I have missed. I am a Javascript developer doing what needs to be done to get things done here, so it's probably something very silly!

Hope someone can help?

I've tried quite a few things, I am starting to go around in circles, the last things I tried was:

On the Handle method, I have put a breakpoint just after the method that creates the 'html', then copied the value from this and posted the azure function with Postman, and received the PDF document all formatted how I expected it.

Additionally I added code further down to save the file, the file incorrectly has the word null as it's content.

Happy to try whatever anyone else suggests?